# How to get latitude and longitude from network provider in kitkat

Tags: android

when i am try to get latitude and longitude from network provider in kitkat the onLocationChanged method is not working. My code is:

```
   double dlat,dlang;
    listener = new MyLocationListener();        
    locationManager = (LocationManager)context. getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000,100, listener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 100, listener);



    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

    public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc)
    {


                dlat = loc.getLatitude();
                dlang = loc.getLongitude();



            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have code that is not working, and you need help with that code, you need to **provide the code**. Please read the site instructions on how to supply a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is happening actually? is dlat/dlong is 0.0 or app is crashing or something else. Please explain your real problem.

Comment: onLocationChanged method is not called in kitkat if i disable gps.But when i enable it it working fine.

Comment: @sumit ... did you get the answer yet ..